# Tesseract OCR not splitting text into different result sets correctly

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I need your help. I am trying to get the emails on the image bellow as separate results and respectively their bounding box's. Somehow Tesseract OCR does not recognize them as separate lines and returns them as a single result.

Current Output - One block

```
Top: 182, Bottom: 512, Left: 533, Right: 852 - 
BCF6CC517E7642BBB21AAF2068E54C28 - Test
D4852831D8CA439EB9D98B54629D1840 - Test
8DFFDO6FA3B44989B224DABDD9292B3E - Test
10E1D83F0D834000AF7BDSDEA48442E8 - Test
6FOA122825AA42159FDEESEBFFAC279B - Test
E719274DA1CE46ADASBDB659812ED684 - Test
ES18EE9D7D7B4AA3ABAT81523F748B24 - Test
?0304b4b-ba1d-4897-8ebe-20bcc3930201 - Test
2ebad2h1-c385-4d84-96c7-bc9082141e1c - Test
```

Desired output - multiple blocks per GUID

```
Top: 182, Bottom: 210, Left: 533, Right: 852 -
BCF6CC517E7642BBB21AAF2068E54C28 - Test
Top: 210, Bottom: 230, Left: 533, Right: 852 -
D4852831D8CA439EB9D98B54629D1840 - Test
Top: 230, Bottom: 250, Left: 533, Right: 852 -
8DFFDO6FA3B44989B224DABDD9292B3E - Test
...
```

I have tried most of the OcrEngineMode's and PageSegmentationMode's.
Nothing worked out correctly.
I also scaled the image from 96 DPI to 300 DPI. Did not help.
Also I went through the documentation and couldn't find a solution.

I am using Tesseract 4

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Are you using any additional image manipulation?

Comment: I am just scaling the image. With or without there isn't a big change

Comment: Could you please edit question to paste expected output

Comment: As I could infer you basically want an array for each email line with there bounding boxes right?

Comment: Yes sir, that is what I want, I need each emails bounding box so that I can programatically click on it

Comment: Also I have control over the subject, I can send different text for subject

Comment: i'm not sure if it's possible by only using tesseract. however i believe you are trying to automate it why not use Gmail API or simple client http libraries or headless browsers? if you're determined to do this way only i guess your best chances are to just use simple maths and divide no of lines and iterate if automated click fails

Comment: sorry i assumed you already tried GetIterator(). did you?

Comment: They are different result entries that are iterated over from the result iterator. I think its possible because Microsoft's Google OCR drive splits them correctly into different lines but cant read the text accordingly.

Comment: so you've tried different modes specifically RIL_TEXTLINE of PageIteratorLevel?

Comment: This is the answer, haven't tried it. It works thanks. Post it as an answer

Comment: glad it helped ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the results, you should set your PageIteratorLevel to
**RIL_TEXTLINE** so that it can split the result paragraphs into separate lines.

```
  var resultIterator = tessBaseAPI.GetIterator();

  var pageIteratorLevel = PageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE;
```